# PHP split URL path string into just 2 string components

Tags: php, arrays, string, url, path

I've got a URL, say, $url='https://www.myurl.com/monkey-48-chicken-broccoli-ham.html'. I want to take the path and split the end into two variables: one containing the number (48), and one containing everything after the number (chicken-broccoli-ham).

While I can divide the returned array from my code below into separate words, the problem is, I don't know how many words will be after the number.

So my question is, how do I split the path into "number" and "everything after number" to store those as variables? Here's what I have so far:

```
$url='https://www.myurl.com/monkey-48-chicken-broccoli-ham.html';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$tag = end($parts);
$tag1 = str_replace("-", " ", $tag);  //replace - with spaces
$tag2 = str_replace(".html", "", $tag1);//delete the ".html" off the end
$tag3 = str_replace("monkey", "", $tag2); //delete the "monkey" word.
```

here's where I need help:

```
$number = ???;
$wordstring = ???;
```

Comment: So you want the result to be as [48, chicken broccoli ham] or [monkey 48, chicken broccoli ham] ?

Comment: thanks result as 48, chicken broccoli ham

Answer (score 1):

```
$url='https://www.myurl.com/monkey-48-chicken-broccoli-ham.html';
preg_match("/([0-9]+)[-](.+)\.html$/",$url,$matches);
```

$matches[1] contains the number

$matches[2] contains "chicken-broccoli-ham"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.myurl.com/monkey-48-chicken-broccoli-ham.html';
$path = basename($url, ".html");
$path = str_replace("-", " ", $path);
preg_match("/(\d+)\s+(.*)/", $path, $match);

echo $match[1] // 48 (number)
echo $match[2] // word after number (chicken broccoli ham)

?>
```

Comment: fantastic thank you. I knew this was an easy one. I obviously missed the preg_match in the manual!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$url = 'https://www.myurl.com/monkey-48-chicken-broccoli-ham.html';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = preg_split('/[0-9]+/', $path);
```

with `parse_url` you get the path part of your url (monkey-48-chicken-broccoli-ham.html) then simply split the string by the number.

Note: you need to remove the - of the beginning and the .html of the end to achieve your desired result.